# could not push anew property to a media object

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to push a new property to a created object but when i do this i get error stating that "Property push does not exist on MediaPlugin".

```
import { File } from 'ionic-native'
import { MediaPlugin } from 'ionic-native';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    public total;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
                public alertCtrl: AlertController,
) { 

                }
media: MediaPlugin = new MediaPlugin("Vanan/audio.mp3");


    startRecording() {      
        try {
            this.AudioFolderCreation();
            console.log("Audio folder created");
            this.starttime()
            this.media.startRecord();
            this.status = false;
            console.log("media recording" +  JSON.stringify(this.media));


        }
        catch (e) {
            this.showAlert('Could not start recording.');
        }
    }


    stopRecording() {
        try {
            this.media.stopRecord();
            this.status = true;  
            this.reset()    
            console.log("Recording stopped Duration is:",this.media);
            console.log("media recording" ,this.media + this.total);
            var obj = this.total;
            this.media.push(obj);
            this.presentPrompt();
        }
        catch (e) {
            this.showAlert('Could not stop recording.');
        }
    }
/* Stopwatch */
    starttime(){
        console.log("timer started");
        if( this.running == 0){
            this.running = 1;
            this.adder()
        }else{
            this.running = 0;
        }
   }

    reset(){
        console.log("timer reset");
        this.running = 0;
        this.time = 0;
        this.total = 0;
        this.Sec = 0;

    }
    adder(){

        console.log("timer incrementor");
        if(this.running == 1){
            setTimeout(()=>{ 
                this.time++;
                var mins = Math.floor(this.time/10/60);
                var sec = Math.floor(this.time / 10 );
                var tens = this.time/10;

                this.total =  mins + ':' +  sec ; 
                this.Sec = sec;               
                this.adder()  

            },100)
        }

    }
```

The timer starts when media started and gets stopped, I need to attach that value to created media object, but when i try it an error shoots out that property push does not exist in mediaplugin

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to add this property but this should fix your error

media: any = new MediaPlugin("Vanan/audio.mp3");

Comment: i followed this link http://www.erikschierboom.com/2016/09/02/ionic2-audio-recorder/ to record audio, if i set media: any = new MediaPlugin("Vanan/audio.mp3");

 this i could not stop my recording @Alex Ryltsov

Comment: Why do you need to add this property?

Comment: actually using media plugin i should get media duration but in my console it returns -1 so i manually  start a stopwatch get the time and then attach it to audio file then on play back i will get its time, over all trying to design a simple audio recorder app with play back